# Failing to load a QRCode

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, barcode-scanner, phonegap

Im having an issue displaying a QRCode generated with phonegap's barcodescanner plugin in my Ionic App. I have another App with the same code and it works just fine, I'll copy my code just in case anyone finds it useful, but its probably not the problem. All I found is that the first time it loads it as MIME text/plain and the next times I try to load it responds with error code 404.
EDIT: I know there are some extra quotes [''] on the path, ignore them as I took pictures a couple hours ago and fixing that hasn't fixed it
Code:

```
encodeText(){  //Function that encodes text. Codigo is a string
    this.barcodeScanner.encode(this.barcodeScanner.Encode.TEXT_TYPE,this.codigo).then((encodedData) => {

        console.log(encodedData);

        this.srcQR= encodedData.file;

    }, (err) => {
        console.log("Error occured : " + err);
    });  
  }][1]

<ion-content padding>   <-- HTML Code !->
  <ion-item>
  <img src={{srcQR}} class="center" *ngIf="srcQR" />
</ion-item>
  <h3>{{codigo}} y {{srcQR}}</h3>
</ion-content>


From my package.json

"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
"@angular/common": "5.2.11",
"@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
"@angular/core": "5.2.11",
"@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
"@angular/http": "5.2.11",
"@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
"@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^4.17.0",
"@ionic-native/camera": "^4.17.0",
"@ionic-native/core": "~4.15.0",
"@ionic-native/fcm": "^4.16.0",
"@ionic-native/file": "^4.17.0",
"@ionic-native/file-path": "^4.17.0",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.15.0",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.15.0",
"@ionic-native/transfer": "^3.14.0",
"@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
"chart.js": "^2.7.3",
"cordova-android": "^7.1.2",
"cordova-ios": "^4.5.5",
"cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3",
"cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-fcm": "~2.1.2",
"cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": "^2.2.6",
"cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
"cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
"cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
"cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
"ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
"npm-check": "^5.9.0",
"phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^8.0.0",
"rxjs": "5.5.11",
"sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
"zone.js": "0.8.26"
```

[First time I try to show de QRcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUAPs.png)

[Second time I try to show the QR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2nQm.png)

[Proof the QR actually exists and QR is being created succesfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcIrf.png)

Let me know if there is anything else I can provide

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed this issue downgrading "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.2.0" to "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "1.1.19". There should be a way to make barcodeScanner without the downgrade, but I couldn't find it.